# How to crawl tweets within exact username

Tags: api, twitter, web-crawler, tweets

I am new for crawling data from tweets.
I went through the twitter library and got consumer key and so on.
However, how could I use those libraries?
Should I write a new driver program using those existing libraries? Or I could just do little change of the existing code.
I am totally confused about the complex process of crawling data.
Could you help me?
Thanks a lot.